# Hausdorff dimension and fractals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

While having a lecture in Measure theory class, the professor mentioned some things about geometrical measure theory, Hausdorff dimension and fractals, something I personally found very interesting and never heard of before.

My question is the following: which fields of mathematics deal with those terms and how can one study them properly and in depth? Any textbooks suggestion would be perfect.

Comment: I think you  can also find Fractal Geometry by Falconer quite interesting (https://www.amazon.co.uk/Fractal-Geometry-Mathematical-Foundations-Applications/dp/0470848618).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book "Introduction to Chaotic Dynamical Systems by Robert Devany "is an excellent source for beginners.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I can see that geometric measure theory can be associated with geometry and topologie..In example i ve heard that you can define measures on topological manifolds and something called Hausdorff measure..In general,I am a great fan of both analysis and geometry and would really want to know how can one can connect those two,which reaserch fields are active on these subjects..Could you enlightend me please,maybe suggest some more books??Thanks in advance!!

Comment: https://users.math.yale.edu/public_html/People/frame/Fractals/

Comment: www.fractal.org/Bewustzijns-Besturings-Model/Fractals-Useful-Beauty.htm